# Swift: Make function universal using generics?

Tags: swift, generics

Ok so I have a function in a few of my Classes for different table cells that looks like this.

```
func open() {
    let array = [position, salary, jobDescription, applyButton]
    switch openVerb {
    case false:
        for i in array {
            i.hidden = true
        }
        openVerb = true
    case true:
        for i in array {
            i.hidden = false
        }
        openVerb = false
    }
}
```

Now this is used a few times so I wanted to make it a universal function so I am not repeating myself. The issue is that each class has a different size array made up of `UIButton` and `UILabel`. The function switches on a `Bool` and then makes all objects in the array hidden or shown.

I tried using generic but I think I have made a big mistake. Help please.

```
func open(inout theSwitch: Bool, inout array: [<T>:UIView]) {
    switch theSwitch {
    case false:
        for i in array {
            i.hidden = true
        }
        theSwitch = true
    case true:
        for i in array {
            i.hidden = false
        }
        theSwitch = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you think you need generics here? Here how I see your function:

```
func open(inout theSwitch: Bool, array: [UIView]) {
    for item in array {
        item.hidden = !theSwitch
    }
    theSwitch = !theSwitch
}
```

Usage:

```
var theSwitch = true
var array = [UIButton]()
var mixedViewsArray = [UIButton(), UILabel(), UIView()]

// switch time:
open(&theSwitch, array: array)
open(&theSwitch, array: mixedViewsArray)
```

You don't need to use reference to original array, since you only change properties in *objects* in that array, so you only use references from it. `open` function will work with any subclass of `UIView` class, like `UIButton` or `UITableViewCell` (you don't even need cast `mixedViewsArray` to proper type, its already `[UIView]`).

Comment: Thank you. I did try it this way but I though I needed inout in front of the array parameter. That must of been what was causing the error. This made me think I needed generics. Will try this method again later

Comment: @AlexanderKaran `inout` keyword before array parameter should not be problem, you just need to use array address instead of array in call by using symbol `&`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to do something similar to this if you want to use generics. See the link for more info on generics and also review swift evolution on GitHub to see if any changes occur in Swift 3. You might also consider using the variant where you declare a variable of Generic type `var elements = Array<UIView>()` or maybe even `var elements = Array<UIControl>()` depending on what class best supplies the properties you'd like to access. Followed by passing that variable array to a function with this signature `func openTableViewCells(inout theSwitch: Bool, inout array: [UIControl]){}`. Please note that I haven't tested these and feel free to refer to the documentation. Another consideration might be to use a set of protocols on the parameter that you are passing... Check the header files for a set of protocols that encompass UIView or UIControl.

Also instead of looping, check out the `forEach` function where you may be able to update the array contents more efficiently.

...
(generic function)

```
func openTableViewCells<T:UIView>(inout theSwitch: Bool, inout array: [T]) {


switch theSwitch {
case false:
    for i in array {
        i.hidden = true
    }
    theSwitch = true
case true:
    for i in array {
        i.hidden = false
    }
    theSwitch = false
}
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Comment: > Also instead of looping, check out the map function where you may be able to update the array contents more efficiently. - You probably mixed up with `forEach`: `array.forEach{$0.hidden = true}`, since `map` is wrong place for update array contents

Comment: @ShadowOf Good catch. I made the change and this got me to re-read the Swift header file for clarification. `forEach` is described as the equivalent of the `for-in` loop and seems appropriate in this case. I've used `map` before and after the review I again realized that it transforms the contents of one array into a different array, which is probably not what the OP wants. Thanks!